# Spring Integration: Dealing with non-MessageProducer handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration 4. I was hoping to define a contract for various integrations whereby an integration needs to implement a generic interface like:

```
public interface Integration {
   Object execute(Map<String, Object> inputs);
}
```

Then to define an integration you define a gateway:

```
<int:gateway service-interface="com.whatever.Integration" ... >
```

I've got this working but am stuck trying to understand how to handle the `execute` method's return value. The first integration I built sends an email and so doesn't really have a return value, i.e. the last element of the workflow is a non-`MessageProducer` mail sender: `<int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter ... >`.

If I change the `execute` method's return type to `void` the integration runs fine, but as soon as I change it to `Object`, the integration runs but never returns. I assume this is because it's waiting for something on the reply channel.

For these type of non-result-producing integrations, is there a way to force a `true` value to be returned or something? I was thinking of trying something like `<int:transformer expression="true">` but I can't put this in my chain after the `<int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter>` because the later doesn't produce a value and so can't precede anything in the chain.

Thus, I'm a bit confused on how to handle non-`MessageProducer` elements in general. Any help is much appreciated.

p.s. If anybody has feedback on the integration architecture proposed above, feel free to chime in on that in the comments too.

Comment: Why are you reinventing reflection? One of the great aspects of Spring Integration is that you can declare strongly-typed service methods and let Spring adapt your message onto them.

Comment: @chrylis Not trying to reinvent reflection, just trying to create a single interface that many integrations (built and dynamically loaded after the base app is deployed) can be executed from. I'm open to suggestions for a better way.

Comment: Just use strong typing. Spring Integration will adapt the method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

TBH your client should know if a reply is expected. In which case, add a second method that returns void.

Or add reply-timeout=0 to the gw and you'll get null returned.

The problem with the latter is you can't tell if a reply producer timed out with requires-reply=false or the ultimate consumer would never return a reply.

Comment: Sure I could create two methods or two interfaces so the caller knows whether there is a return value - fair suggestion. So should I assume that when a non-MessageProducer handler is used, it has to be the last handler in that particular "path" and nothing can ever come after it? Maybe email is a bit of an edge case because most things would return something like an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: If you want to return a reply on such a flow, make the last channel before the ultimate consumer (channel adapter) a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`; you can then subscribe something to return a reply after a successful mail send. `<int:transformer input-channel="lastChannel" order="2" expression="'OK'"/>` (use `order="1"` on the channel adapter). The transformer will be invoked after the mail adapter and return `OK` to the gateway method. You don't need two interfaces; you can have multiple methods on an interface with different settings for each in the `<gateway/>`.